# HTML multiple form post

Tags: html, post, html-select, multiple-forms

I have two forms in my page.

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off"> 
            <h3><span>Number : </span>
                <span class="min-width"><select class="form-control" id="num" maxlength="255" name="num_selector" onchange="this.form.submit();" autofocus>
<option value="0001" selected="selected">0001</option>
</select></span>
            </h3>
</form>

<form action="/enter" method="POST" name="form2">
       <input class="btn btn-default btn-orange has-spinner" type="submit" value="enter" name="enter">
</form>
```

When i click the enter button on the form2, it end up posting to the same URL(which is what defined in form1). form1 is getting posted instead form2.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit them using the java-script separatly.

document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

```
<input type="button" name ="enter" value="enter" OnClick="postData('FORMID')" />
function postData(formId){
    document.getElementById(formId).submit(); 
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Still my first form is getting posted.

Comment: This is for example you have to customize it to work for yours.

let me still you need i can code that for you ?